# Вопрос про *.lib и С++

Tags: c++

Здрасвтвуйте.
У меня есть билиотека, представляющая из себя набор файлов заголовков и исходников и написанная на С++. В ней описано много различных классов, которые используются в других моих проектах. Можно ли мою библиотеку скомпилировать в статическую, а потом в других моих проектах подключать ее и использовать классы из нее. Сам на С++ пишу не очень долго и таких тонкостей не знаю.

Answer (score 5):

Можно. Отгружать будете .lib (или .а -- зависит от платформы) и заголовки

Answer (score 1):

Можно, но осторожно. Библиотека и использующая его программа должны быть скомпилированны одним и тем же компилятором. Некоторые ключи компиляции должны совпадать.

Как вариант, вместо lib можно использовать obj-файлы, которые создаются автоматически. Они работают так же, как и lib, но, в отличие от lib, на каждую единицу компиляции (cpp-файл) приходится один obj.

Comment: 1. Ну требование "одним компилятором" слишком строго. Правильнее будет "совместимы" (правда на ответ кто с кем совместим я ответить не готов). 2. .lib как раз и создаются из .obj (в linux -- .a из .o). И, библиотечными утилитами объектный файл можно извлечь из библиотеки.

Comment: >Правильнее будет "совместимы" (правда на ответ кто с кем совместим я ответить не готов).

 Я читал, что должно быть скомпилированно именно одним компилятором. Попадалось это много раз. Сам я не пользуюсь lib и использую только один компилятор, поэтому не проверял. Но могу предположить, что компиляторы по-разному называют C++ функции и делают разное выравнивание структур и классов.

>.lib как раз и создаются из .obj (в linux -- .a из .o).

 Это я знаю. Я имел в виду, что lib создавать необязательно. Можно использовать просто obj, причём таким же способом.

Comment: @GLmonster а вот obj вместо lib -- это круто. Постоянно править Makefile или включать нужные obj в проект (а их много)... Или включить все и надеяться, что умный линковщик выкинет лишние?

Comment: MinGW выдает .o файлы в формате COFF, MSVC по идее тоже в COFF (или, как вариант, MS-COFF. COFF - подмножество MS-COFF) - они между собой совместимы. А вот компиляторы Borland (теперь уже Embarcadero) выдают объектники в формате OMF. Для преобразования из COFF в OMF и обратно есть соответствующие утилиты.

Это все под Windows. Под Linux объектные файлы имеют формат ELF.